# google maps and reverse geocoding using html5API?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

why does this:

```
        function initCoords() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, locationError);
  } else {
    showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
  }
}
initCoords();
function locationError(){
  alert('"Your browser does not support Geolocation!"');
}
function initialize(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var acc = position.coords.accuracy;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // Debugging
    console.log(position.coords);
    console.log("Accuracy: "+acc+"\nLatitude: "+lat+"\nLongitude: "+lon);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

    // Google Maps API
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
  function codeLatLng(position) {
   lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
  codeLatLng();
```

always return this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined
```

on this line:

```
    function codeLatLng(position) {
   lat = position.coords.latitude;
    enter code here
```

it shows me the map just not the marker with the address...
I've also tried this: 
codeLatLng(position);

Comment: Because you are calling `codeLatLng()` without a `Position` parameter in the last line? Works as designed so far. Did you mean to put the code there in the `initialize()` callback? Because *that* is given a `Position` argument

Comment: I see the same thing as the previous commentor. You are calling CodeLatLng() without any value, which would be picked up as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the call to CodeLatLng() into the Initialize() function after you render the google map, and pass it the position argument. See comments above.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript"      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script>
 function initCoords() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, locationError);
  } else {
    showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
  }
}
initCoords();
function locationError(){
  alert('"Your browser does not support Geolocation!"');
}
function initialize(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var acc = position.coords.accuracy;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // Debugging
    console.log(position.coords);
    console.log("Accuracy: "+acc+"\nLatitude: "+lat+"\nLongitude: "+lon);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

    // Google Maps API
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  codeLatLng( position );
}
  function codeLatLng(position) {
   lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
 </script>
 </head>
  <body onload="">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```